# How to ignore error from get_data_yahoo without for loop

Tags: python

When I run the following code with a list of tickers, I get an error:

`pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '2008-01-01')`

> KeyError: 'Date'

Is there a way to skip the ticker that caused this error and move to the next ticker, 
WITHOUT using for loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right now, we don't know the structure of your code. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you have multiple `tickers`, I'm not sure how you have achieved this without a loop...

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
try:
  pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, '2008-01-01')
except:
  pass
```

Having said that it is not recommended that you use 'pass' which ignores ALL errors completely...you should use something like this:

`except ErrorWithCode as e:
    print("Received error with code:", e.code)
    pass`

to only ignore the error that you know its cause.

Comment: `except: pass` is almost never the right thing to do, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: I agree...that was a quick answer but I was just trying to provide error handling mechanism that he can look further into

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review. Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.